# Implementing ADFS SSO with Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, single-sign-on, adfs, delphi-10.2-tokyo, intraweb

I have a Delphi web application developed using Intraweb framework (IW 15), currently user are authenticated with database of the application. Now we need to enable this application with SSO.

Our customer uses `SAML2.0` and `WS-Federation` protocols with `ADFS`.
I have searched over the internet regarding ADFS and SSO but could not find any details about this.

Is this something where I can send a simple HTTP requests and get a token or some authentication information and allow user to login ?

Is there any component (in built with Delphi or third party) available to implement SSO with ADFS using SAML2.0 ?

Comment: I ended up using Shibboleth service provider to achieve this https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/Home

Comment: Are you still using Shibboleth? I'm looking for a solution too